# there a function on my canvas Js graph when i click on pie chart the column chart should act according to it

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

I'm trying to change my column chart dynamically when I click on the pie chart.
I have created a interface and a function on my canvas Js graph when I click on pie chart the column chart should act according to it, No bells ringing

So here is the code below
`<a>https://jsfiddle.net/2kLwt70f/`

Refer Subject Revenue By Category
https://canvasjs.com/samples/dashboards/web-analytics-real-time/overview/

Comment: you want the  effect as seen in the demo?

Comment: Yes sir , I want the same concept

Answer (score 1):

this code does the job:

```js
$(function() {
  var pieChartValues = [{
      y: 39.16,
      color: "#1f77b4",
      name: "Apple",
    },
    {
      y: 21.8,
      indexLabel: "Grapes",
      color: "#ff7f0e",
      name: "Grapes",
    },
    {
      y: 21.45,
      indexLabel: "Banana",
      color: "#ffbb78",
      name: "Banana",
    },
    {
      y: 5.56,
      indexLabel: "Mango",
      color: "#d62728",
      name: "Mango",
    },
    {
      y: 5.38,
      indexLabel: "Orange",
      color: "#98df8a",
      name: "Orange",
    },
  ];

  var columnChartValues = [{
      y: 686.04,
      color: "#1f77b4",
    },
    {
      y: 381.84,
      color: "#ff7f0e",
    },
    {
      y: 375.76,
      color: "#ffbb78",
    },
    {
      y: 97.48,
      color: "#d62728",
    },
    {
      y: 94.2,
      color: "#98df8a",
    },

    {
      y: 686.04,
      color: "#1f77b4",
    },
    {
      y: 381.84,
      color: "#ff7f0e",
    },
    {
      y: 375.76,
      color: "#ffbb78",
    },
    {
      y: 97.48,
      color: "#d62728",
    },
    {
      y: 94.2,
      color: "#98df8a",
    },

    {
      y: 686.04,
      color: "#1f77b4",
    },
    {
      y: 381.84,
      color: "#ff7f0e",
    },
    {
      y: 375.76,
      color: "#ffbb78",
    },
    {
      y: 97.48,
      color: "#d62728",
    },
    {
      y: 94.2,
      color: "#98df8a",
    },
  ];

  var piechart;
  renderColumnChart(columnChartValues);
  renderPieChart(pieChartValues);

  function renderPieChart(values) {
    piechart = new CanvasJS.Chart("pieChart", {
      title: {
        text: "Pie Chart",
        fontFamily: "Verdana",
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: "normal",
      },

      legend: {
        horizontalAlign: "left",
        verticalAlign: "center",
      },

      animationEnabled: true,
      data: [{
        click: clickHandler,
        indexLabelFontSize: 15,
        indexLabelFontFamily: "Monospace",
        indexLabelFontColor: "darkgrey",
        indexLabelLineColor: "darkgrey",
        indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
        type: "pie",
        legendMarkerType: "square",
        showInLegend: true,
        toolTipContent: "<strong>#percent%</strong>",
        dataPoints: values,
      }, ],
    });
    piechart.render();
  }

  function renderColumnChart(values) {
    var columnchart = new CanvasJS.Chart("columnChart", {
      title: {
        text: "Multi-Series Column Chart",
        fontFamily: "Verdana",
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: "normal",
      },

      animationEnabled: true,
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      axisX: {
        interval: 2,
        intervalType: "month",
        labelFontColor: "#717171",
        lineColor: "#a2a2a2",
        tickColor: "#a2a2a2",
      },
      axisY: {
        gridThickness: 0,
        labelFontColor: "#717171",
        lineColor: "#a2a2a2",
        prefix: "$",
        tickColor: "#a2a2a2",
      },
      toolTip: {
        backgroundColor: "#737580",
        borderThickness: 0,
        cornerRadius: 0,
        fontColor: "#ffffff",
        fontSize: 16,
        fontStyle: "normal",
        shared: true,
      },
      data: [{
        indexLabelFontSize: 15,
        indexLabelFontFamily: "Monospace",
        indexLabelFontColor: "darkgrey",
        indexLabelLineColor: "darkgrey",
        indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: values,
      }, ],
    });

    columnchart.render();
  }

  function clickHandler(e) {
    //keep all color of part of datas exploded
    let colorsToKeep = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < piechart.options.data[0].dataPoints.length; i++) {
      if (piechart.options.data[0].dataPoints[i].exploded === true) {
        let piecolor = piechart.options.data[0].dataPoints[i].color.trim();
        columnChartValues.map(function(e) {
          if (e.color.trim() == piecolor && !colorsToKeep.includes(piecolor)) colorsToKeep.push(piecolor);
        });
      }
    }


    let toKeep = [];
    let idx = 0;
    if (colorsToKeep.length > 0) {
      columnChartValues.map(function(e) {
        if (colorsToKeep.includes(e.color)) {
          e.x = idx++;
          toKeep.push(e);
        }
      });

    } else {
      // need to do that instead renderColumnChart(columnChartValues);  maybe a bug?
      columnChartValues.map(function(e) {
        e.x = idx++;
        toKeep.push(e);
      });
    }

    renderColumnChart(toKeep);
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Web Analytics - Real Time</title>

  <!-- stylesheets -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="pieChart" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="columnChart" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Other solution:

```js
$(function () {
var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("pieChart", { 
  title: {
    text: "Pie Chart",
    fontFamily: "Verdana",
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "normal"
  },

  legend: {
    horizontalAlign: "left",
    verticalAlign: "center",
    fontFamily: "calibri",
    fontSize: 14    
  },

  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: "#737580",
    fontColor: "#ffffff",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontStyle: "normal",
    shared: false
  },

  animationEnabled: true,

  data: [
    { 
      click: onClick,
      visible: true,
      type: "pie",
      showInLegend: true,
      dataPoints: [  
        { y: 39.16, color:"#1f77b4", name:"Apple"},
        { y: 21.8,  color:"#ff7f0e", name:"Grapes" },
        { y: 21.45, color:"#ffbb78", name:"Banana"},
        { y: 5.56,  color:"#d62728", name:"Mango"},
        { y: 5.38,  color:"#98df8a", name:"Orange"}
      ]
    }]
});
chart1.render();

var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("columnChart", {
  title: {
    text: "Multi-Series Column Chart",
    fontFamily: "Verdana",
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "normal",
  },

  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: "#737580",
    fontColor: "#ffffff",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontStyle: "normal",
    shared: false
  },

  animationEnabled: true,

  data: [
    {
      visible: true,
      type:"column",
      color:"#1f77b4",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 271 },
        { x: 20, y: 55  },
        { x: 30, y: 450 },
        { x: 40, y: 465 },
        { x: 50, y: 95  }
      ]},
    { 
      visible: true,
      type:"column",
      color:"#ff7f0e",
      dataPoints: [ 
        { x: 10, y: 121  },
        { x: 20, y: 225  },
        { x: 30, y: 650  },
        { x: 40, y: 565  },
        { x: 50, y: 155  }
      ]},
    {
      visible: true,
      type:"column",
      color:"#ffbb78",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 281 },
        { x: 20, y: 185 },
        { x: 30, y: 50  },
        { x: 40, y: 165 },
        { x: 50, y: 195 }
      ]},
    {
      visible: true,
      type:"column",
      color:"#d62728",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 81  },
        { x: 20, y: 55  },
        { x: 30, y: 350 },
        { x: 40, y: 145 },
        { x: 50, y: 125 }
      ]},
    {
      visible: true,
      type:"column",
      color:"#98df8a",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 81  },
        { x: 20, y: 55  },
        { x: 30, y: 350 },
        { x: 40, y: 145 },
        { x: 50, y: 125 }
      ]}   
  ]
});
chart2.render();

var pieData = chart1.options.data;
var columnData = chart2.options.data;

function onClick(e) {

  if(e.dataPoint.exploded == false) {
    columnData[e.dataPointIndex].visible = false;
    var notVisible = columnData.every(function(dataSeries) {
      return (!dataSeries.visible);
    });

    if(notVisible) {
      for(var i = 0; i < columnData.length; i++) {
        columnData[i].visible = true;
      }

    }
  }
  else {

    for(var i = 0; i < columnData.length; i++) {

      if(i == e.dataPointIndex || pieData[0].dataPoints[i].exploded == true)
        columnData[i].visible = true;
      else
        columnData[i].visible = false;
    }
  }
  chart2.render();
}

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Web Analytics - Real Time</title>

  <!-- stylesheets -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="pieChart" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="columnChart" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

your error was in this part of code:

```
var notVisible = columnData.every(function(dataSeries) {
  return (!dataSeries.visible);
});
```

an equivalent without every is :

```
var notVisible = true;
for(var i = 0; i < columnData.length;i++){
  if(!columnData[i].visible) continue;
  notVisible = false;
  break; 
}
```

Fo helping you about some array function in js

```
// Here's a simple array of "person" objects
var people = [ 
    { name: "John", age: 20 }, 
    { name: "Mary", age: 35 }, 
    { name: "Arthur", age: 78 }, 
    { name: "Mike", age: 27 }, 
    { name: "Judy", age: 42 }, 
    { name: "Tim", age: 8 } 
];
 
// filter is equivalent to Where
var youngsters = people.filter(function (item) {
    return item.age < 30;
});

console.log("People younger than 30");   
console.log(youngsters);

// map is equivalent to Select
var names = people.map(function (item) {
    return item.name;
});

console.log("Just the names of people"); 
console.log(names);
  
// every is equivalent to All
var allUnder40 = people.every(function (item) {
    return  item.age < 40;
});

console.log("Are all people under 40?"); // false
console.log(allUnder40);

// some is equivalent to Any
var anyUnder30 = people.some(function (item) {
    return  item.age < 30;
});

console.log("Are any people under 30?");  
console.log(anyUnder30); // true

// reduce is "kinda" equivalent to Aggregate (and also can be used to Sum)

var aggregate = people.reduce(function (item1, item2) {
    return  { name: '', age: item1.age + item2.age };
});

console.log("Aggregate age");     
console.log(aggregate.age); // { age: 210 }
```